# Unable to upload files on google app engine with django

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am new to python and django. Currently I am creating a project with help of python and django and using Google app engine as deployment server. In this process I have created a small application which takes file as input and I want to store that file somewhere in my project so that I can refer that file for next REST calls. In order to do this I have referred below artical
https://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-filetransfers#reference-filetransfers-api-module

However After reading this artical I found out that the function `direct_to_template` is deprecated in django latest builds. So experts recommends to use `TemplateView.as_view` instead of `direct_to_template` . However I am not able to replace `direct_to_template` as it is by  `TemplateView.as_view` .

Can anybody please help me to convert my below line into `TemplateView.as_view` format.

```
direct_to_template(request, 'upload/upload.html',
    {'form': form, 'upload_url': upload_url, 'upload_data': upload_data})
```